# Getting one extra green line while using Material-UI in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI in my react app i just copy input field code from documentation everything is fine but there is one extra blue line. Please tell me how to remove that line

```
<div className={classes.margin}>
        <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="flex-end">
          <Grid item>
            <AccountCircle />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <TextField id="input-with-icon-grid" label="With a grid" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: @RyanCogswell he is clearly explained the issue

Comment: @ThilinaDinithFonseka I disagree. The image shows two lines (one green and one blue). The TextField accounts for only one of those lines, and it is not clear what the source of the second line is. My guess is that the TextField underline was desirable and the other line (of unknown source) was not.

Comment: its clear and theoretically you are correct. but practically its appear with two lines. both were from material UI. please check the below answer I gave to solve that issue. this issue is correctly posted. this is exactly happening without any custom css or styles. just only using material UI.

Answer (score 0):

use this !
the reason this happening cause importing material UI as normal HTML import ( using script tags). it is conflict with the npm installation as a node package. so two of those styles and js actions are applying cause those two lines. the following code will disable HTML script importing style's underline to the component.

```
 <TextField... InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true, }} />
```

Comment: You should provide a bit of explanation

Comment: added things i figured and it might not be 100% correct.